# Algorithm to generate all points in an N-dimensional space satisfying a given set of constraints

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I encountered this interesting problem a few weeks ago: Given an n-dimensional space and a "step size" value that lies between (0,1], generate all points that satisfy the following constraints:

- The value of each dimension of a point is a multiple of the "step size"
- The value of each dimension of a point ranges between 0 and 1 inclusive. For example, a 2D point (x,y) should satisfy 0=<x,y<= 1
- The sum of values of all dimensions must be equal to 1 ***(Updated)***

Example 
 Input:
 stepSize = 0.5 and numDimensions = 3 (i.e., 3D space) 
 Output:
 `0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
  0.0, 0.5, 0.5
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0
  0.5, 0.0, 0.5
  0.5, 0.5, 0.0
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0`

Since we need to find all possible points, I thought of a recursive solution. Here is my code:

```
class PointEnumeration {
    static class Point {
        List<Float> dimensions; //a list of float where index i is the (i+1)'th dimension 

        Point(Point p) {
            this.dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
            this.dimensions.addAll(p.dimensions);
        }

        Point(int size) {
            this.dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                //Initialize all dimensions to 0.0f
                this.dimensions.add(0.0f);
            }
        }

        void incr(int pos, float i) {
            float val = dimensions.get(pos);
            dimensions.set(pos, val + i);
        }

        void set(int pos, float i) {
            dimensions.set(pos, i);
        }


        float get(int pos){
            return dimensions.get(pos);
        }
    }


    static List<Point> findPoints(float stepSize, int numDim) {
        if (stepSize > 1) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        List<Point> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(float i = stepSize; i <= 1; i+=stepSize) {
            findPointsHelper(i, numDim, 1.0f, 0, new Point(numDim), res);
        }
        return res;
    }

    static void findPointsHelper(float stepSize, int numDim, float sum, int start, Point curr, List<Point> res) {
        if (sum == 0.0) {
            res.add(new Point(curr));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = start; i < numDim; i++) {
            float temp = sum;
            float val = curr.get(i);
            curr.incr(i, stepSize);
            findPointsHelper(stepSize, numDim, sum - stepSize, i + 1, curr, res);
            curr.set(i, val);
            sum = temp;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        List<Point> res = findPoints(0.25f, 4); //Tried 1.0f, 3 and 0.5f, 3 as well
        for (Point p : res) {
            for (Float coord : p.dimensions) {
                System.out.print(String.valueOf(coord) + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work correctly for a few test cases that I tried. Example output for (stepSize=0.5f and numDimensions=3):
`0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 
0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 
0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,`

I have a few questions:

1. Is my approach to solving this problem correct?
2. What is the exact time complexity of my solution? I claimed that it was exponential but was unable to correctly articulate the time complexity in terms of number of dimensions/step size/number of points. What would be the best approach to reason about time complexities for the above problem and for recursive algorithms like these in general?
3. If my understanding of the time complexity being exponential is correct, is there a more efficient algorithm to solve this particular problem?

---

**EDIT**
I missed a third constraint: Sum of all values of a dimension must sum to 1.0 (Apologies, I forgot to mention this earlier).

Comment: ask yourself: where is point `1.0, 0.5, 0.0` (and similar) in the output?

Comment: You could generate all the points for the 1 dimensional case, getting S say, and then take the cartesian product of dim copies of S.

Comment: As @BeyelerStudios points out, either the two constraints you give are wrong, or your example solution is wrong.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Apologies, I updated the question with one other constraint that I had forgotten to mention.

Comment: while this invalidates all previous answers on complexity, it makes @Andy's point on *for loop with floating point numbers* even more relevant: you'll only be able to sum up parts of `1 / k` where `k` is an integer, use `k` directly to avoid floating point errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine provided a great solution to this problem. As some people here, mentioned in their answers, it is a problem that boils down to generating all the ways of writing a integer 'm' as a sum of 'k' non-negative integers. Here is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers) detailing this problem.

Incorporating Andy's feedback of working with integers, here is the updated java code with some comments. Please not this is the java adaptation of the solution provided by my friend:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class PointEnumeration {
    static class Point {
    //a list of integer where index i is the (i+1)'th dimension
    List<Integer> dimensions;

    Point(int step, int numDim){
        this.dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < numDim; i++) {
            this.dimensions.add(step);
        }
    }

    Point(int step, Point p){
        this.dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
        this.dimensions.add(step);
        this.dimensions.addAll(p.dimensions);
    }

    int get(int pos) {
        return dimensions.get(pos);
    }
}


private static List<Point> findPoints(int steps, int numDim){
    if(numDim == 1){
        //Only one dimension, add the `steps` to the only dimension
        return Arrays.asList(new Point(steps, 1));
    }

    List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if(steps == 0){
        //Nothing left, create a point with all zeroes
        return Arrays.asList(new Point(0, numDim));
    }

    //Iterate on the steps
    for(int i = 0; i <= steps; i++){
        //Recurse on the remaining steps and
        //reduce the dimension by 1 (since this dimension will
        // be handled in the next for-each loop)
        List<Point> remaining = findPoints(steps-i, numDim-1);
        for (Point point : remaining) {
            //Append the i'th step to the remaining point
            Point complete = new Point(i, point);
            //This is a complete point for the i'th step
            // and current dimension
            result.add(complete);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float stepSize = 0.2f;
    int numDim = 4;

    int steps = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 / stepSize);
    List<Point> res = findPoints(steps, numDim);
    for (Point p : res) {
        for (int coord : p.dimensions) {
            //Convert integer steps to float value
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(coord <= 0 ? 0.0f : (coord / (float) steps)) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of points =" + res.size());
}
```

1. Turns out my approach (and my original code) was wrong, as I was not computing all points correctly - the code did **not** compute points that had steps different from each other, example: [0.0 0.2 0.8 0.0].
2. Time complexity: (as mentioned in the math exchange [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)): Its equal to the number of possible points that is given by: C(n+k-1, k-1) where n = (1/stepSize) and k = numDimensions. An example: for **stepSize = 0.2** (== 5 as an integer), and **numDimensions = 4**, the number of points possible is **56**.

Answer (score 3):

You have `V = ValuesCount = 1 + 1/stepSize` possible values for every dimension and `nD` dimensions. 
There are V points in 1D, V*V points in 2D, V^3 in 3D, `V^nD` points in nD-dimensional space.

Note that you can generate all point coordinates in simple for-cycle

```
  for k = 0..V^nD - 1 
      represent k in V-ary number system
      m-th digit of k is coordinate of the k-th point in m-th dimension   
     (divide by (V-1) to normalize to range 0..1)
```

Example for your V=3, nD=3 case:

```
  k = 15(dec) = 120(trinary)
  first (right) digit is 0, second is 2, third is 1
  coordinates (0.0, 1.0, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is my approach to solving this problem correct?

I've not looked at your code, but your example output is missing several points. There should be 27.

Note that using a for loop with floating point numbers can lead to problems, owing to the accumulated error in the loop variable. It is better to loop on integers, and then divide inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
  System.out.println(i / 9.0);
}
```

instead of

```
for (double i = 0; i <= 1; i += 1.0 / 9.0) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

([Compare the output of the two](http://ideone.com/7mePQE) - notice inaccuracies in the second case as well as printing one fewer line)

> 3. is there a more efficient algorithm to solve this particular problem?

There are `1 + 1/stepSize` values for each coordinate; there are `numDimensions` coordinates. Hence, there should be `(1 + 1/stepSize)^numDimensions` distinct points in that space.

Hence, the optimal complexity of iterating through all the points is `O((1 + 1/stepSize)^numDimensions)`.

Comment: I have updated the question with a third constraint (that my code and sample output captures but was not explicitly list among the constraints). Thanks for the insight into the for-loop with floating point numbers - that was really useful! Given the additional constraint of the values summing to 1.0f, the number of "valid" distinct points must reduce. What would be the complexity in this case?

Comment: It effectively reduces `numDimensions` by 1, since you can infer the last coordinate from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Now, after edit, this is **absolutely** different problem.

This is combinatorial task of generation of all **partitions** of number N into N+1 parts when order of parts is important (**compositions**). Delphi code (divide values by N to get your 'coordinates').

Note that there are C(2n,n) such compositions (C(6,3)=20), where C - number of combinations.

```
var
  Cmp: array of Integer;
  N, NP, first, nonzero: Integer;
begin
  N := 3;
  NP := N + 1;
  SetLength(Cmp, NP);  //zero filled
  Cmp[N] := N;
  #output Cmp array
  while Cmp[0] <> N do begin
    first := Cmp[0];
    Cmp[0] := 0;
    nonzero := 1;
    while Cmp[nonzero] = 0 do
      Inc(nonzero);
    Dec(Cmp[nonzero]);
    Cmp[nonzero - 1] := first + 1;
    #output Cmp array
  end;
```

output for N=2 and N=3

```
0 0 2 
0 1 1 
1 0 1 
0 2 0 
1 1 0 
2 0 0 

0 0 0 3 
0 0 1 2 
0 1 0 2 
1 0 0 2 
0 0 2 1 
0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 
0 2 0 1 
1 1 0 1 
2 0 0 1 
0 0 3 0 
0 1 2 0 
1 0 2 0 
0 2 1 0 
1 1 1 0 
2 0 1 0 
0 3 0 0 
1 2 0 0 
2 1 0 0 
3 0 0 0
```